# Add more field in SignupForm using django-allauth

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

**Models:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(self, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

**Forms:**

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'nationality', 'bio')

    def signup(self, request, user):
        # Save your user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()

        user.profile.nationality = self.cleaned_data['nationality']
        user.profile.gender = self.cleaned_data['bio']
        user.profile.save()
```

**Views:**

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'myproject.forms.CustomSignupForm',}
```

This process isn't work. **Error is: Model class all_auth.models.Profile doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.**

How can I solve it? Or, How can i add more field with SignupForm using django-allauth?

Comment: isn't it `allauth` rather than `all_auth`?

Comment: @dirkgroten:  this was my project name. Now i change it.

Comment: So `all_auth` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @dirkgroten: it's my project name not app name.. I create forms.py and models,py in my project folder.. I also tried creating app and create forms.py and models,py into the app. but query is not save into Profile model in signup process ..

Comment: All your models must be in an app that is registered in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: @dirkgroten: error is solved now. but data is not save into Profile model

Comment: @dirkgroten: I do it. Create an app then put it into INSTALLED_APPS. but form not save the data into Profile Model

Comment: I think you should use `save` function, not `signup`.
see this one https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#signup-allauth-account-forms-signupform

Answer (score 6):

Create an application, such as accounts and it has this code, but you need to create a database only after creating this code, it is more accurate to perform the first migration in the project

```
accounts/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)


accounts/forms.py

from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django import forms
from .models import *

class SimpleSignupForm(SignupForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=12, label='Телефон')
    def save(self, request):
        user = super(SimpleSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        user.save()
        return user


settings.py
...
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'accounts.forms.SimpleSignupForm'}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'


accounts/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```